# Javac forbid calling a specific JDK method

Tags: java, compilation, javac, deprecation-warning

Is there any way to make `javac` give an error or a warning when calling, for instance, `AbstractStringBuilder#append(Object)`?

In this specific case, would it also catch the `+` syntactic sugar?

Comment: No. But why do you need this? I suspect that you really have a different problem you want to solve, and you think this is the solution (it sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). If you explain why you need this, then maybe someone can give you a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: Since after all you are trying to help, I'll pass the condescension. There are obviously any number of reasons one might want to do it. I have an object that replaced a String in a refactoring operation and I'd like to know if it's being implicitly converted somewhere, and an obvious suspect is `append(Object)`. Does anyone have a way to do that? I imagine a javac processor could do it, but I'd rather not have to write one.

Comment: Not meant to be condescending. `javac` does not have what you are looking for as a standard feature, there's no easy way to do this.

Comment: Since in a comment you speak of **refactoring** this appears to be more in the realm of support offered by your favorite IDE. Searching for references to a given method is of course a feature typically supported by IDEs.

Comment: I'm not aware of any IDE that can find all usages of this specific method. It's too central, has too many overloads, and there's `+`. For domain-specific methods, that would be of course the solution.

Comment: If there is no way to do that, then it's life. Thanks.